# how do I completely wipe a Windows Update bluetooth driver, and all associated configuration/installation settings, from my installation?

Tags: windows-vista, bluetooth

*Due the circumstances surrounding the first installation I suspect the original file (or more likely a related registry setting applicable to this drivers' installation) does not get removed on driver uninstallation, and has been corrupted.*

---

I encountered issues with a Bluetooth USB dongle while configuring it with a bluetooth headset.

The offending driver is BthAvrcp.sys. Windows had to contact Windows Update to discover (and download) it the first time.

I can delete the offending driver/file from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\, disconnect my network (no Windows Update contact), and Uninstall the device, but BthAvrcp.sys still gets copied back to this folder (this tells me the file is cached somewhere else that I need to clean) when I install the device (with network still disabled), and on load, BSOD's.

**My objective is to replicate the virgin system state before I began driver installation the first time.**

- **How can I erase related these driver-registry settings?**
- **is it safe to delete registry items / parent folders of registry settings that reference this file?**

Comment: Try with Windows Restore http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-8-system-restore-guide/

Comment: unfortunately, it is unsuccessful in restoring. I suppose a reformat...

Comment: Wipe and reload will certainly fix it but I was expecting a more graceful solution

Comment: I feel like drivers have gotten too complicated and hidden to troubleshoot these days

Comment: That's why I love drivereasy , it always work even if is slow as hell http://www.drivereasy.com/